# Kendall conditional independence test statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, kendall-tau

Given the two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ and a random variable $Z=\{0,1\}$ that denotes groups, the following null-hypothesis is devised:

$$H_0:X\perp Y\:\vert\:Z$$

The alternative hypothesis is that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent (in some way) based on the following test statistic:

$$T=K^{*2}_1+K^{*2}_2$$

where $K^*$ is the standardized version of Kendall statistic $K$ that can be used for testing independence.

Within the $z=1$ group, the statistic $K_1^*$is used for testing independence, and, similarly, within group $z=2$, $K_2^*$ is appropriate for testing independence. The statistics $K_1^*$ and $K_2^*$ are standardised statistics with asymptotic N(0,1) null distributions.

Has anyone a clue as to how this test statistic is derived from the null-hypothesis? What does $T$ signify? Understanding how $T$ is derived would allow me to better formulate the alternative hypothesis in words.

Comment: Could you state your null and alternative in the same form? It looks like there's a mistake but because one is in words and the other is in symbols it's hard to be sure. Do you have a reference for the test?

Comment: @Glen_b, indeed. I corrected it. The symbols were correct. The $H_a$ signifies dependence, but because I do not understand how $T$ is derived, I do not know exactly in what way.